# jquery click event won't trigger even with the right selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html, smooth-scrolling

I'm not really a jquery expert so please bear with me. I have "googled" but couldn't find any solution.
Here is the code:

```
<div id="navbarResponsive" class="collapse navbar-collapse col-auto">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="navbar-nav text-uppercase">
  <li id="menu-item-1725" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1725 nav-item"><a href="#page-top" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Home</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1739" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1739"><a rel="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Services</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1735" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1735 nav-item"><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li id="menu-item-1736" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1736 nav-item"><a href="#about" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the portion of the script/snippet:

```
(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict
  $('a.nav-link.js-scroll-trigger').click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
  $('.js-scroll-trigger').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
  $('li').find('a.js-scroll-trigger').click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(e) {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') ==
        this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname ==
        this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +
                                          ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 54)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

The problem is that it only triggers `$('a')` and ignores the rest of the selectors.
I have tried checking it on the browser:

console - https://www.screencast.com/t/sikIcYY1J

sources using debugger -- https://www.screencast.com/t/TgbNhIb1usy

It appears that it was targeting the correct selectors but fails to trigger the condition as shown above.  My smooth scrolling won't work anymore unless I place `$('a')` as the only condition. It used to work few days before, I dunno what happened. Something must have triggered it not to work.  Could someone please enlighten me? Answers would really be appreciated, many thanks...

Comment: Is there any JS code added next to it? Maybe someone unbind the click.

Comment: In your console screenshot it shows the event target as `a.nav-link.js-scroll-trigger` …?

Comment: Do you add the `js-scroll-trigger` class using js, or does it exists in the html code right from the beginning? What does `console.log( $('.js-scroll-trigger').length)` show if you place it right after the `"use strict"; // Start of use strict`

Answer (score 1):

change `target.length` to `$(target).length`

add `e.preventDefault();`

fix `var target = this.hash;`

but, why do you need this for? `if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {`

All you need is this:

```
$(function() {
  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var target = this.hash;       

      if ($(target).length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top - 54)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return;
      }
    });
});
```

---

Anyway, here is the fix to your script.

```js
$(function() {
  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') ==
      this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname ==
      this.hostname) {
      var target = this.hash;
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');


      if ($(target).length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top - 54)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        console.log(target);
        return;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="navbarResponsive" class="collapse navbar-collapse col-auto">
  <ul id="primary-menu" class="navbar-nav text-uppercase">
    <li id="menu-item-1725" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1725 nav-item"><a href="#page-top" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1739" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1739"><a rel="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Services</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1735" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1735 nav-item"><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1736" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1736 nav-item"><a href="#about" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<p>ggwgsgwg</p>
<p> </p>
<p>ggwgsgwg</p>
<p>ggwgsgwg</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>ggwgsgwg</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p id="services">ggwgsgwg</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>ggwgsgwg</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>ggwgsgwg</p>
<p>ggwgsgwg</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>ggwgsgwg</p>
<p>ggwgsgwgv</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax error.

```
(function($) {
```

should need to change

```
$(function() {
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/bha0y5ob/)

Comment: This is not a syntax error, but might be a logical error. But since `$('a').click` works, it indicates, that the problem is not related to the ready event.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS "(function($) {" to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

With this, the events work for me.

Comment: Also, second case seems to not work, as an event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one element, and the event only needs to bubble up one level. Only alert 1,3 and 4 will work:https://jsfiddle.net/ep7hmo63/14/

Comment: Alert 2 not fires because '.js-scroll-trigger' click event not elevate 'a', because there is no 'a' tag under this class. This is not syntax a fault.

Answer (score 0):

I have another script which I made that adds classes to make the smooth scrolling work. It was called AFTER the script above, so I moved it BEFORE inside the functions.php (Wordpress). The scripts started to work again. Silly of me not to notice that. Sorry for the trouble, & thank you, guys...